# How to stop Looping on javascript after several times

Tags: javascript, loops

I am trying to make disappear loop using javascript, the codes running well.. but i want to make the loop stop after several times.. this is the codes :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

     var j = 0;
     var delay = 9000; //millisecond delay between cycles
     function cycleThru(){
             var jmax = $("ul#cyclelist li").length -1;
             $("ul#cyclelist li:eq(" + j + ")")
                     .animate({"opacity" : "1"} ,400)
                     .animate({"opacity" : "1"}, delay)
                     .animate({"opacity" : "0"}, 400, function(){
                             (j == jmax) ? j=0 : j++;
                             cycleThru();
                     });
             };

     cycleThru();

});
```

What should i do if i want to stop the loop after 10x?

Thanks for the help

Comment: If your 10X means when 10 times of j becoming jmax, then how about not call `cycleThru` function after 10X as `(j == jmax) ?  j=0 & max++ :  j++; if (max <= 10) cycleThru();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way to solve this would be to accept a `cycles` parameter in `cycleThru`, which is used to specify the amount of cycles after which recursion is stopped.

```
function cycleThru(cycles = Infinity) {
```

You then add a guard clause to the recursive function to stop the recursion.

```
if (cycles <= 0) return;
```

When you recursively call `cycleThru` reduce the `cycles` by one.

```
cycleThru(cycles - 1);
```

Finally pass the amount of cycles with the initial `cycleThru` call.

```
cycleThru(10);
```

Resulting in the following code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var j = 0;
  var delay = 9000; // millisecond delay between cycles

  function cycleThru(cycles = Infinity) {
    if (cycles <= 0) return;

    var jmax = $("ul#cyclelist li").length - 1;
    $("ul#cyclelist li:eq(" + j + ")")
      .animate({"opacity" : "1"} ,400)
      .animate({"opacity" : "1"}, delay)
      .animate({"opacity" : "0"}, 400, function () {
        (j == jmax) ? j=0 : j++; // or: j = (j + 1) % jmax
        cycleThru(cycles - 1);
      });
  };

  cycleThru(10);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Take this line `var jmax = $("ul#cyclelist li").length -1;` outside the function. Else every time `cycleThru` is called it will create new `j`

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var jmax = $("ul#cyclelist li").length - 1;

      var j = 0;
      var delay = 9000; //millisecond delay between cycles
      function cycleThru() {

        $("ul#cyclelist li:eq(" + j + ")")
          .animate({
            "opacity": "1"
          }, 400)
          .animate({
            "opacity": "1"
          }, delay)
          .animate({
            "opacity": "0"
          }, 400, function() {
            if (j !== max) {
              j++;
              cycleThru();
            }
          });
      };

      cycleThru();

    });
```

Comment: this line make loop stop after 1x, i tried length -10 but still same